# iOS How to get more then 100 values from array Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an app, in which I have a question, which I save in array, if I get 100 values I array I get the error:

Class to save data:

```
class QuestionManager {
var question: String?
var answerA: String?
var answerB: String?
var answerC: String?
var answerD: String?

init(question: String, answerA: String, answerB: String, answerC: String, answerD: String){

    self.question = question
    self.answerA = answerA
    self.answerB = answerB
    self.answerC = answerC
    self.answerD = answerD
}
```

Func to load data from server:

```
    var questions = [QuestionManager]()
    let query = PFQuery(className: dbQuery.query)
    query.findObjectsInBackground{ (objects, error) in
        if error == nil && objects != nil {
            for object in objects! {

                questions.append(QuestionManager(
                    question: object["question"] as! String,
                    answerA: object["answer1"] as! String,
                    answerB: object["answer2"] as! String,
                    answerC: object["answer3"] as! String,
                    answerD: object["answer5"] as! String

                ))
            }
            self.questionText = questions[self.arrayIndex].question!
            self.answer1 = questions[self.arrayIndex].answerA!
            self.answer2 = questions[self.arrayIndex].answerB!
            self.answer3 = questions[self.arrayIndex].answerC!
            self.answer4 = questions[self.arrayIndex].answerD!
            self.loadDataToBox()
        } else {
            print("Error")
        }

    }
```

> Fatal error: Index out of range

I have list with question which are more the 300 questions, how i can fix it?

Comment: where you declare arrayIndex ??

Comment: Where does "self.arrayIndex" get set?

Comment: @Sh_Khan in the top of my VC

Comment: @kd02 it's get information from model

Comment: Offtopic but: instead of if error == nil && objects != nil {, use this: guard error == nil && let objects = objects else { print("Error"). Swift isn't java :).

Comment: Please get rid of all those forced unwraps.

Answer (score 3):

The default [`limit`](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#/c:objc(cs)PFQuery(py)limit) on a `PFQuery` is 100 objects.  If you want to retrieve more, up to the maximum of 1000, you need to set the `limit` property before you execute the fetch.

If you want to retrieve more than 1000 values you will need to issue additional queries.

Comment: yes,  but your code should also never try and access an index beyond `questions.count`